How to list all the procedures Mathematica uses when doing some computation and how to control it?
If I compute:
Factor[x^3 + x - 2]

It will give me the expected result:
$(x-1) \left(x^2+x+2\right)$
But if I try the following:
Factor[{Abs[x^3 + x - 2], x^3 - x^2 - x + 1}]
% /. Abs[y_] -> Factor[y]

It will yield:
$\left\{x^3+x-2,(x-1)^2 (x+1)\right\}$
It seems that the second code not only factor the argument of Abs but also apply Simplify or Expand. How can I make it show the argument of Abs in the factored form when computing this code?
Also: When I compute both of these codes, Mathematica applies some computational procedures. Does Mathematica has something that shows exactly what procedures were applied?

You can try Trace as in Trace[Factor[{Abs[x^3+x-2],x^3-x^2-x+1}],TraceInternal->True] but this can be hard to read. There are ways to filter it and improve the layout if you search this forum.

To clarify why you're getting that result, you need to understand the difference between -> and :>. Evaluate your code after replacing Abs[y_] -> Factor[y] with Abs[y_] :> Factor[y].

As for seeing what "procedures" Abs uses, I don't think you can do that, since Abs is a kernel function. But there could be some magic that I'm unaware of.

I don't know what Mathematica uses internally, but you could use Times @@ (x - SolveValues[x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 == 0, x])

In general, Mathematica does not show its work, for simplicity's and usability's sake. In an example like this one, the work might be rather simple and thus worth inspecting. But in complex functions that implement large fields of study (e.g. DSolveValue) into a one-liner, even if you could convince it to divulge them its intermediate steps are more likely to be simply incomprehensible to the average user than in any way helpful.
